# How do I simulate ajax GET with data params using Postman?

Tags: jquery, ajax, postman

I need to simulate API call using Postman but I only know how to do it in jQuery's ajax. Here's the ajax :

```
ajax: {
    url : API_URL,
    data: function (data) {
        data.authenticityToken = TOKEN;
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to do the API call above using Postman? I'm using GET method by the way.

Comment: Copy specific url into postman and hit send. Not really clear what specific problem is in doing that

Comment: There's data parameter on it. Where should I put it? I tried to put it on Headers or Body but they're not working.

Comment: There is no request body in  a GET.  Use url query params the same way jQuery ajax converts them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What parameters are you expecting to pass? You could do it the same way you pass query parameters in the web browser.

For example;

http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&oq=stackoverflow
**q** and **oq** are the query parameters

Postman here:

[image]